# Converting char * to CString inside a catch block in a UNICODE application

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, try-catch

I have this code inside an MFC application:

```
catch(cv::Exception &ex)
    {
        USES_CONVERSION;
        MessageBox(A2T(ex.what()), _TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);

    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
error C3204: '_alloca' cannot be called from within a catch block
```

How can I fix this error?

The poriginal solution for converting const char * to CString was from my search over internet, but I could not find any information how to do it inside a catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `USES_CONVERSION`

Change: `MessageBox(A2T(ex.what()), _TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR);`

To:  `MessageBoxA(ex.what(), "Error", MB_ICONERROR);`

Note the extra 'A' on the end of `MessageBoxA`.

Comment: I used in this way:  MessageBoxA(NULL, ex.what(), "Error", MB_ICONERROR);

Answer (score 0):

try using _resetstkoflw in the catch block.

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain how this solves the problem.